# Why print(subprocess.check_output()) does not recognize '\n'?

Tags: python, subprocess

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess

print(subprocess.check_output("ls -l ~", shell=True))

print("Testing\nTesting")
```

[image]

Please pay attention to the first line of the output. Why is python printing all in the same line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

As show above return of `checkoutput` is `bytes` type.

Comment: Well, it solves the problem. .decode() is a built-in function the, right?

Comment: In a interactive python interpreter, `s.decode` return `<built-in method decode of bytes object at SOMEWHERE>`. In CPython you can find the source code at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/57c781048915e45d15eaa348c51ec01b12cc170a/Objects/bytesobject.c#L2199 @muyustan